# Manipulate string in python (replace string with part of the string itself)

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

So I am trying to transform the data I have into the form I can work with. I have this column called "season/ teams" that looks smth like "1989-90 Bos"

I would like to transform it into a string like "1990" in python using pandas dataframe. I read some tutorials about pd.replace() but can't seem to find a use for my scenario. How can I solve this? thanks for the help.

FYI, I have 16k lines of data.
A snapshot of the data I am working with:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change that field from "1989-90 BOS" to "1990" you could do the following:

```
df['Yr/Team'] = df['Yr/Team'].str[:2] + df['Yr/Team'].str[5:7]
```

If the structure of your data will always be the same, this is an easy way to do it.

Comment: thanks! as you said, it fits this scenario well as my data is all consistent.

Comment: Do note that it will generate noise in scenario like "1999-2000" turning into 1900. However, it can be easily fixed by replacing the specific value as it is uncommon in my dataset

Answer (score 0):

If the data in your `Yr/Team` column has a standard format you can extract the values you need based on their position.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Yr/Team': ['1990-91 team'], 'data': [1]})

df['year'] = df['Yr/Team'].str[0:2] + df['Yr/Team'].str[5:7]

print(df)

        Yr/Team  data  year
0  1990-91 team     1  1991
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.Series.str.extract` to extract a pattern from a column of string. For example, if you want to extract the first year, second year and team in three different columns, you can use this:

```py
df["year"].str.extract(r"(?P<start_year>\d+)-(?P<end_year>\d+) (?P<team>\w+)")
```

Note the use of named parameters to automatically name the columns

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html